# Nearest neighbor and distance between points and lines

Tags: oracle, gis, spatial, nearest-neighbor

In oracle spatial I have two tables (**AVALREGULACAO** and **ATROCOADUTOR**) representing points and lines, respectively.

The structure of both tables is as follows:

AVALREGULACAO (**295 point records**)
  IPID [number(10)]
  GEOMETRY [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]

ATROCOADUTOR (**12536 line records**)
  IPID [number(10)]
  GEOMETRY [MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY]

I need to find the nearest ATROCOADUTOR neighbor from each AVALREGULACAO and calculate the distance between them

**AVALREGULACAO_IPID | ATROCOADUTOR _IPID | DISTANCE**

I’ve used 2 options

**1**

```
SELECT /*+ ORDERED */ A.IPID, B.IPID, MIN(SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE(sdo_cs.make_2d(A.GEOMETRY), sdo_cs.make_2d(B.GEOMETRY), 0.005)) as DISTANCE
FROM AVALREGULACAO A, ATROCOADUTOR B 
GROUP BY c_b.IPID,c_d.IPID;
```

It takes quite a long time to compute - It generates a huge output of 295 x 12536 = 3 698 120 possible combinations (Cartesian product).  Furthermore the csv file output cannot accommodate all this records (1 048 576 rows limit)

I only need 295 records corresponding to the 295 AVALREGULACAO.

**2**
I’ve also tried/adapted another query with the nearest neighbor (nn) operator

```
PROMPT IPID, nearest_IPID, distance  
  select /*+ ORDERED USE_NL(s,s2)*/
         s.IPID,
         s2.IPID as nearest_IPID,
         TO_CHAR(REPLACE(mdsys.sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_cs.make_2d(s.GEOMETRY),sdo_cs.make_2d(s2.GEOMETRY),0.05), ',','.')) as distance
    from AVALREGULACAO s,
         ATROCOADUTOR s2
   where s2.IPID in (select IPID
                from AVALREGULACAO s3
               where sdo_nn(s3.GEOMETRY,s.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1) = 'TRUE'
                       and s3.IPID <> s.IPID
                       and rownum < 2)
 order by 1,2;
```

This query takes forever - I need to shut down the process before it ends.

I guess I'm missing the point on how to optimize/filter the desired results.

Any tips on how to efficiently solve this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

PS:
@Boneist. Thanks a lot for the input.

Unfortunately I got an error after applying your query (still trying to work the semantics/syntax of new commands KEEP, dense_rank)

```
SELECT a.ipid a_ipid,
       MIN(b.ipid) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST order by sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1)) b_ipid,
       MIN(sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_cs.make_2d(a.geometry), sdo_cs.make_2d(b.geometry), 0.005)) AS distance
FROM   avalregulacao a
       INNER JOIN atrocoadutor b ON sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1) = 'TRUE'
GROUP  BY a.ipid;
```

**Error**

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT a.ipid a_ipid,
MIN(b.ipid) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST order by sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1)) b_ipid,
MIN(sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_cs.make_2d(a.geometry), sdo_cs.make_2d(b.geometry), 0.005)) AS distance 
FROM avalregulacao a 
INNER JOIN atrocoadutor b ON sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1) = 'TRUE'
GROUP  BY a.ipid
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 45
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-29907: foram encontradas etiquetas em duplicado em invocações primárias
29907. 00000 -  "found duplicate labels in primary invocations"
*Cause:    There are multiple primary invocations of operators with
           the same number as the label.
*Action:   Use distinct labels in primary invocations.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're probably after something like:

```
SELECT a.ipid a_ipid,
       MIN(b.ipid) KEEP (dense_rank FIRST order by sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1)) b_ipid,
       MIN(sdo_geom.sdo_distance(sdo_cs.make_2d(a.geometry), sdo_cs.make_2d(b.geometry), 0.005)) AS distance
FROM   avalregulacao a
       INNER JOIN atrocoadutor b ON sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1) = 'TRUE'
GROUP  BY a.ipid;
```

This joins both tables on the nearest neighbour function, which should reduce the number of rows being returned.

The `MIN(b.ipid) KEEP (dense_rank first order by sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1))` simply returns the lowest b.ipid value for the lowest difference.

(I think this query will work as is, but I can't test it. You might have to do the join and have `sdo_nn(a.GEOMETRY,b.GEOMETRY,'sdo_batch_size=10',1)` as a column in a subquery and then do the group by in the outer query.)